# libtidy not working in php

Tags: php, tidy

I am using libtidy with php. I am using xampp and it shows that tidy support is enabled. But when i use it in my code then it shows the following warning

```
repairString() [function.repairString]: Could not load configuration file tidy-file.php
```

i also tried using the object-oriented version but i again got the warning

```
tidy_repair_string() [function.tidy-repair-string]: Could not load configuration file tidy-file.php
```

i have kept the tidy code in a separate file called `tidy-file.php`. it looks like this

```
$options = array("output-xhtml" => true,"clean" => true, "drop-proprietary-attributes" => true,"drop-font-tags" => true,"drop-empty-paras" => true,"hide-comments" => true); 
function getXHTML($html)
{
$xhtml=tidy_repair_string($html,$options);
return $xhtml;
}
```

what can be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've shown here, you're trying to use a variable that's defined outside the function. You need to pull it inside like so:

```
function getXHTML($html)
{
  $options = array("output-xhtml" => true,"clean" => true, "drop-proprietary-attributes" => true,"drop-font-tags" => true,"drop-empty-paras" => true,"hide-comments" => true); 
  $xhtml=tidy_repair_string($html,$options);
  return $xhtml;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. but a function can access global data and here `$options` is a global array. then why didnt it work?

Comment: Does php follow different scope rules than c/C++

Comment: @lovesh Yes, in order for a global variable to be usable in function scope, you have to use the `global` statement to pull it in like so: `global $options;`. After doing so it will be available to the function.